# issue in layout android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I am trying to display two text view in LinearLayout. but one is showing little big and one is little small...if I keep both text view font size same than its showing fine but if I make second text view font size small then view also getting small. image is like below

[image]

and my XML is like below. what I am missing ?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="15/12/2016"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:background="@color/light_grey"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `image` is for  required  design ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK image is showing issue...I need both row height same...in image you can see second view with date have little small height then first one

Comment: So, what do you want in your layout? do you want equal both textview equal width in your linearlayout?

Comment: @DharmaKshetri I want both text view height same....You can see that second view has little small height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting the background image at the LinearLayout instead

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/light_grey"          
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Comment: You just close-voted a question with a custom reason stating "this is spam". There are red flags for that, please use those to actually delete the post and alert the moderators to destroy the account, as opposed to leaving the spam lying around on the site until someone comes by to actually delete post+user.